# Dynamic stretching of text

Tags: spacing, xetex, header-footer, fontspec

For the needs of a running title (in header), I would like the text of a running title (in header) to be stretched over the page. So far, I stretch it manually (using `LetterSpace` and `WordSpace` in `fontspec`), but my chapters can have pretty short or very long titles, so either short chapters will be not-so-stretched, or long chapters will look horrible.

Is there a way to adapt the stretching dynamically?

Comment: You know about the short version of chapter titles which can be given with the optional argument of `\chapter`, don't you? This is the normal way to handle longer chapter titles in headers.

Comment: Ah, interesting @Martin. I use this to typeset chapter titles properly on their page while keeping them correct in the ToC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `\resizebox{\linewidth}{!}{Your headline}` from the `graphicx` package to stretch the text over the full line width or any other width you want.
This of course will give shorter chapter titles a larger font than longer ones. I'm not sure what you want exactly.

Comment: Thanks. I don't expect the font size to adapt, rather the amount of spaces between letters and words (an effect *a la* `\textls`).

Comment: @Raphink: I see. You could measure the natural text width and compare it with the available width, but you would also need to know the amount of letters and words to calculate the correct letter spacing. This doesn't seem very easy. You could use `\resizebox{<some width>}{\height}{Your headline}` to stretch the text without changing the height, but this wouldn't look good.

Comment: right, keeping the height and resizing the width might look very ugly.

Comment: @Raphink: It will look ugly also expanding the spaces.

Comment: Hehe... *de gustibus et coloribus...*

Answer (score 1):

TeX can increase the natural width of a `\hbox` by a given absolute amount like shown below. You probably want to increase that amount based on the natural width of a given text and I'm sure someone more versed with TeX's boxes could provide a macro that adds, say, 10% of extra spacing by first measuring the natural width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{\hbox spread 15pt{Headline with 15pt of extra spacing}}
\section{\hbox spread 5pt{Headline with 05pt of extra spacing}}
\end{document}
```

[image: Two headlines with different spacing]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question. However, `\spaceskip 3.333pt plut 1fill minus 0pt` could be useful to you

Answer (score 0):

I have actually chosen another solution to my problem.

Since I capture the current chapter title as `\chaphead` during `\chapter` assignment in order to display it in the header, I am actually redefining `\chaphead` to be shorter in the case of a very long chapter title:

```
% Use first argument for ToC (lots of space there)
% Second argument for title display (on two lines)
\chapter[Pourquoi le charisme se change souvent en charismanie]%
  {Pourquoi le charisme\\ se change souvent en charismanie}
% Reset running title to be shorter
\renewcommand{\chaphead}{Pourquoi le charisme se change souvent\dots{}}
```